# Postmaster Hook Parse Error

Tags: postmaster

ExpressionEngine 2.5.2 - Build Date: 20120606
Postmaster 1.2.0

I was wanting to try to create a hook for Postmaster but when I click "add hook" I get the following error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDFOREACH in /var/www/html/teamnet/system/codeigniter/system/core/Loader.php(727) : eval()'d code on line 249
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to contain your EE version and Postmaser version?

Comment: I will be working a fix to this bug in the next couple of days. I haven't been able to duplicate it yet because I am slightly behind on my other projects after being sick for the past week.

Comment: Not a problem, I've been sick as well so I know the feeling. I hope you're feeling better and thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a number of critical bug fixes to Postmaster's latest developer build this evening. I have test thoroughly and can't any more issues. I created and triggered hooks without issue.

I know I emailed you the updated branch before, but I think you run into new issues which have also been fixed. So... just email support[at]objectivehtml.com and I will send you the updated code.